# How can I achieve this CircularProgressIndicator in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

does anyone know how to achieve a `CircularProgressIndicator()` as on the screenshot below in Flutter?

[image: CircularProgressIndicator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the *IOS equivalent* of the `CircularProgressIndicator()`. You can use [`CupertinoActivityIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoActivityIndicator-class.html). [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AENVH-ZqKDQ) is a YouTube video by the Google team on how to use it.

You have to import `cupertino` first:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
...

return CupertinoActivityIndicator()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct way to achieve that in Flutter. If you use  CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive it will be shown in Android as Android style and in iOS like native clockwise turning ticks style:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(          
            width: 50.0,
            height: 50.0,
            child:  
         CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
        strokeWidth: 7,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              valueColor: Colors.green,
              
            ));
  }
```